# Video tag - not playing in IE, getting "Invalid Source"

Tags: html, iis, html5-video, mime-types, internet-explorer-11

I know there are a lot of articles out there on this subject, and I've looked at about a dozen so far.  Most of the answers tackle mime types for mp4, webm.

In IE11 at least (possibly 10, 9 as well) I'm getting a black video player box with "Invalid Source" and nothing else.

Here's my code:

```
<video id="someid" autobuffer="true" controls="true" preload="auto">
<source src="../sarlacc/thisismyvid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="../sarlacc/thisismyvid.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
A sorry message goes here.
</video>
```

The mime types for both are set in the site's mime types in IIS 6.  When I add the mime type to Default Web Site parent, the site goes down for a reason currently not obvious to me.  Is it because somehow the mime types are conflicting between Default and the child site?

Comment: I tried, no joy.  Thanks though.

Comment: I dont have success with IE11 playing mp4/ogg video streams. It sucks :( Chrome works though (but ogg only).

Comment: I can get MP4 to play in Chrome with the above code.